# How to change control row and column definition index at runtime?

Tags: wpf, grid

I want to change row and column definition index of a control in grid, like my textbox having index 2nd row and 3rd column in a grid now i want to move to 3rd row and 5th column so how to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Grid.SetColumn(textBox, 5);
Grid.SetRow(textBox, 3);
```

Comment: bt Grid belongs to which grid?

Comment: @nag Grid belongs to the Grid in which placed the TextBox. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Grid.SetRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrow.aspx) and [`Grid.SetColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn.aspx), usually for [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) such a static method exists on the owning type.